# Java library for converting rest urls to jax-rs methods

Tags: java, routes, jax-rs

I have a collection of jax-rs resources, such as

```
@Path("/api/v1/ping")
public class PingResource {

    @GET
    public String ping(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
        return "pong: " + name;
    }

}
```

I want figure out how urls map into resource methods, e.g.

```
public class ResourceMethod {
    Method method;
    Object[] arguments;
}

public interface UrlToResourceMapper {
    ResourceMethod mapToResource(HttpServletRequest request);
}

UrlToResourceMapper mapper = new UrlToResourceMapperImpl(Arrays.asList(PingResource.class));
ResourceMethod resourceMethod = mapper.mapToResource(new RequestImpl("GET", "http://host/api/v1/ping?name=josh", ...));
assertEquals(PingResource.class.getMethod("ping"), resourceMethod.method);
assertEquals(1, resourceMethod.arguments.length);
assertEquals("josh", (String)resourceMethod.arguments[0]);
```

Is there a library that implements something like the `UrlToResourceMapper` interface? e.g. Is there a class within Jersey that does this? Everything I've found so far either invokes the method, or only makes the method accessible from within the context of an executing request. I don't want to invoke the method, and I don't want to submit a request (I don't want filters to be invoked, for instance). I just want a library that tells me what invocation results from a given request.

Comment: Is this for API documentation purposes?

Comment: Could be. Could also be for dispatching requests. Or for lightweight functional testing. The jax-rs libraries I've looked at don't separate concerns very well. You can't use them piecemeal. I asked the question because I'm trying to figure out how I can keep control of the request life-cycle. A single `processRequest` method that calls method.invoke() in the middle is a lot easier to understand than a bunch of filters scattered about in different places linked together with xml configuration. `UrlToResourceMapper` lets me keep that control. Does it exist? Is it not the essence of jax-rs?